# Why is rspec so slow under rake? ruby_noexec_wrapper?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

I'd been having problems with my spec code taking a lot longer than expected to run, but when I tried to run them under `rspec-prof`, the problem seemed to go away.  Eventually I tracked the difference down to running `rake` natively compare to running it under an interpreter.

Running just `rake` takes 75 seconds, but running `ruby $(which rake)` takes only 12 seconds.  That's over *five times* as quicker.  Take a look:

```
$ rake
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby -w -S rspec spec/args_spec.rb spec/levels_spec.rb spec/opts_spec.rb spec/run_spec.rb spec/split_spec.rb spec/unit_spec.rb
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:516: warning: method redefined; discarding old revision
..................................................

Finished in 1 minute 14.39 seconds
50 examples, 0 failures

$ ruby `which rake`
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby -w -S rspec spec/args_spec.rb spec/levels_spec.rb spec/opts_spec.rb spec/run_spec.rb spec/split_spec.rb spec/unit_spec.rb
..................................................

Finished in 12.88 seconds
50 examples, 0 failures
```

Looking at the contents of the `rake` "wrapper binary" shows in the "#!" line that it is running under the interpreter - `ruby_noexec_wrapper` - and sure enough running the command as:

```
ruby_noexec_wrapper $(which rake)
```

Gives the same slow 75 seconds run.

Any ideas why this should be the case?

Apart from avoiding running rake directly is there anything that can be done to improve it?  Since that's a standard way to wrap gems to be binaries, isn't that potentially slowing down all gem-packaged tools?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the `ruby_noexec_wrapper` file (rvm 1.16.17):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

original_file=ARGV[0]
ARGV.shift
$PROGRAM_NAME=original_file

require 'rubygems'
begin
  require 'rubygems-bundler/noexec'
rescue LoadError
  warn "unable to load rubygems-bundler/noexec" if ENV.key?('NOEXEC_DEBUG')
end

eval File.read(original_file), binding, original_file
```

As far as I can see, the two warning areas are the two `require` statements. The first, `require 'rubygems'`, is not likely to be a problem, as ruby 1.9+ [does this automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2711857/1087866).

I think the problem is in `require 'rubygems-bundler/noexec'`. If you [take a look at what it's doing](https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler/blob/master/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb) you can see that it's setting up bundler. This involves requiring gems, which is likely to be the source of your slow startup.

Gems shouldn't do a whole lot when they are loaded, but unfortunately many of them make some mistakes in that area. The only way to solve this is to try and work out which gems are causing the majority of the slowness and find alternatives where possible.