# Errors when using require gosu MAC OS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal, rubygems

I'm trying to run this script and I'm using Coderunner 2

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gosu'
 class Ball 
   def initialize(the_window)
   @x = 200
   @y = 200
   @w = 20
   @h = 20
   @image = Gosu::Image.new(the_window, "ball.png", false)
end

def draw
    @image.draw(@x, @y , 1)
end
end
class GameWindow < Gosu::Window
    def initialize
    super 800,600, false
    self.caption = "Paddle Game"
    @ball = Ball.new(self)
    end
    def update

    end
    def draw
    @ball.draw
    end
end
window = GameWindow.new
window.show
```

**

It kicks back an error message:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require':
    cannot load such file -- gosu (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 
   `require'
    from paddle_game.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

and I've installed Ruby 2.0.0 and the gems...when I try to install gosu this is the error I get:

```
Mac-Users-iMac-763:~ macuser$ sudo gem install gosu
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing gosu:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gosu-0.10.4/ext/gosu
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r                     .    /siteconf20151124-93492-9a029w.rb extconf.rb
 The Gosu gem requires some libraries to be installed system-wide.
 See the following site for a list:
 https://github.com/jlnr/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-OS-X

creating Makefile

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gosu-0.10.4/ext/gosu
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gosu-0.10.4/ext/gosu
make "DESTDIR="
compiling stb_vorbis.c
compiling gosu_wrap.cxx
compiling Audio-Audio.cpp
compiling Bitmap-Bitmap.cpp
compiling Bitmap-BitmapIO.cpp
compiling DirectoriesUnix.cpp
compiling FileUnix.cpp
compiling Graphics-BlockAllocator.cpp
compiling Graphics-Color.cpp
compiling Graphics-Graphics.cpp
compiling Graphics-Image.cpp
compiling Graphics-LargeImageData.cpp
compiling Graphics-Macro.cpp
compiling Graphics-Resolution.cpp
compiling Graphics-ResolutionApple.cpp
compiling Graphics-TexChunk.cpp
compiling Graphics-Texture.cpp
compiling Graphics-Transform.cpp
compiling Input-Input.cpp
compiling Input-TextInput.cpp
compiling Inspection.cpp
compiling IO.cpp
compiling Math.cpp
compiling Text-Font.cpp
compiling Text-Text.cpp
compiling Text-TextApple.cpp
compiling TimingApple.cpp
compiling Utility.cpp
compiling UtilityApple.cpp
compiling Window.cpp
linking shared-object gosu.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress'
make: *** [gosu.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gosu-0.10.4 
   for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin- 
  13/2.0.0/gosu-0.10.4/gem_make.out
```

I've tried to research and different suggestions, but I can't get any further at the moment. Just wondering any ideas what I could be doing wrong or if I should use a different editor? Not sure why the 'require' isnt working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couple things I noticed:

1. Your `class Ball` is indented one space.
2. You need to `end` your `class Ball` method.
3. You have an extra `end`after the `def draw` function.
4. Your methods need indenting.
5. Your indenting is inconsistent (pick 2 or 4 spaces and stick with the convention)
6. Seee this thread re: [`require 'rubygems'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711779/require-rubygems)

This version of your code launches a window on my system (Ubuntu 14 with Ruby 2.3 and using rvm 1.11.3.9 I have downloaded and [bundled](http://bundler.io/) gosu 0.10.8):

```
# require 'rubygems'
require 'gosu'

# class Ball 
#   def initialize(the_window)
#     @x = 200
#     @y = 200
#     @w = 20
#     @h = 20
#     @image = Gosu::Image.new(the_window, "ball.png", false)
#   end
# end
# 
# def draw
#   @image.draw(@x, @y , 1)
# end

# end

class GameWindow < Gosu::Window
  def initialize
    super 800, 600, false          # <-- width, height, fullscreen=false
    self.caption = "Paddle Game"
#     @ball = Ball.new(self)
  end

  def update
  end

  def draw
#     @ball.draw
  end
end

window = GameWindow.new
window.show
```

If you are using Ruby [Gosu](https://www.libgosu.org/) on OSX, you might want to go here:

https://github.com/gosu/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-OS-X

For what it is worth, I was getting the same "LoadError" after installation and using "bundler" in the project directory took care of the gem dependency. I visited the Linux version of the GOSU website:

https://github.com/gosu/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Linux

and after entering this in the command line:

```
user@ubuntu:~/Ruby/gosu_project$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libsdl2-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libpango1.0-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libfreeimage-dev libopenal-dev libsndfile-dev
```

```
user@ubuntu:~/Ruby/gosu_project$ gem install gosu
```

I also had to invoke:

`user@ubuntu:~/Ruby/gosu_project$`**bundle**

http://bundler.io/ - also works with MacOSX...

per: https://github.com/gosu/gosu/wiki/ruby-tutorial

This gosu file:

```
# basic Gosu: gui test file

require 'gosu'

class TestWindow < Gosu::Window   # <-- inherits from Gosu Window Super class

  def initialize
    super 640, 480, false         # <-- width, height, fullscreen = false
    self.caption = "successful gosu test window"
  end

  def update
  end

  def draw
  end

end


TestWindow.new.show
```

...loads a 640x480 window

```
user@ubuntu:~/Ruby/gosu_project$ ruby gosu_test.rb
```